# Laravel 5: similar to array_push but for JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

working with PHP (Laravel 5). If I would assign the following to a JSON:

```
$client->contactperson=['name'=>'John Doe', 'phone'=>'0123456789'];
```

and somewhere else in the code I have another like this:

```
$client->contactperson=['name'=>'Adam Doe', 'phone'=>'0123456789'];
```

it would result like this because the second assignment will override the first:

```
"contactperson": { 
        "name": "Adam Doe",
        "phone": "0123456789"
    }
```

Is there something similar to array_push for arrays that that I can use with JSON string to add the second assignment without replacing the first. So that it  would look similar to this:

```
"contactperson": {"name": "John Doe",
        "phone": "0123456789"},
        {"name": "Adam Doe",
        "phone": "0123456789"}
```

Comment: Is there any issue to initiate array and manage your data as array and finally assign to  `$client->contactperson` using `json_encode`

Comment: Use $client->contactperson[] = ['name'=>'John Doe', 'phone'=>'0123456789'];

Comment: Your responses from serverside must have fixed format to make it predictable to parse it from clientside. so You've to use array of them if You want to pass it like "contactperson": [{"name": "John Doe",
        "phone": "0123456789"},
        {"name": "Adam Doe",
        "phone": "0123456789"}]

Comment: I don't want to lose the eloquent relationship by changing it to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from b0s3 isn't complete.

```
$client->contactperson = [$client->contactperson];
$client->contactperson[] = ['name' => 'John Doe', 'phone' => '0123456789']
```

The first answer would go like that:

```
$client = [name, phone, [name, phone]]
```

Except you want something like

```
$client = [[name, phone], [name, phone]]
```

So first you should create a multidimensional array.

Comment: I got it working by creating an "array of arrays" and then adding the next with array_merge. Thanks Codel96!

Comment: Yeah sorry for the expression "array of array", French and don't know how to call it. array_merge is a good solution too, glad being helpful.  EDIT: Oh right it's just like in French, **multidimensional array**!

Answer (score 3):

Use this -

```
$client->contactperson[] = ['name'=>'John Doe', 'phone'=>'0123456789'];
```

It will assign it to a new index rather than replacing the old one.

Comment: `array_push()` would also work but have to take care of the keys. :)

Comment: But `array_merge()` won't how you are using it. It's also the wrong method for this task.

Comment: Missed that one. `array_merge` also go through the same issue.

Comment: $client->contactperson[] = ['name'=>'John Doe', 'phone'=>'0123456789']; gives the following error: Indirect modification of overloaded property App\models\Client::$contactperson has no effect